# Java Class Fields Definition

Tags: java, oop

I've came across with the next code lines, which are part of the implementation of a Node class :

```
public class Node {

    private String data;
    private Node next;
```

I wonder how is it possible to use `private Node next;` as a field of Node ? How come this 'self-instance' is legal and how does it work ?
I'll be grateful if anyone could explain this.

Comment: It's not a self reference. It's a reference to an object of the same type.

Comment: Just as the name suggests `next` should refer to a `Node` object. And there would definitely be a public method that takes Node object and assigns that to `next`

Comment: An application of this is used in a Linked list data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not a self-instance, but, it will refer a instance of an object on memory, of the same type, a `Node`.

Att: The reffered object can be itself.

Comment: That's what i've asked - how come the reffered object could be itself ?

Comment: Well, you can look at `next` variable as a recipient that recieves an address of memory of `Node` type. When u create a `Node`, it can store on `next` variable (an recipient) the memory address of an variable of `Node` type. It´s clear?

Comment: Or, u can see a `Node` as a house. Every house has an address, and inside of every house u can have a paper with address of other houses.
In my house, i can put on this paper the reference of my own house.

Answer (score 2):

`Node next` will just keep a reference to a different instance of `Node` class, which means `Node` class `has-a` `Node`.

I'm guessing that class belongs to a simple 'linked list' implementation, where each node keeps a reference to the next node in the list.

Comment: Doesn't need to be a different instance.

Comment: Well, not necessarily, but most probably.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant something on these terms

```
  public class Node {

        private int info;
        private Node next;

        Node(int info, Node next) {
            this.info = info;
            this.next = next;
        }
```

When you actually use this in a `linked list` kind of structures the `next` points to another (or same) kind of object of type `Node`